# Yii2 DatePicker within Modal

Tags: datepicker, yii2, modal-dialog

> when I use the kartik\date\DatePicker within Modal,but it's report error that like  `https://******.com/assets/d9620747/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css.map Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`.plz help me;

My Controller's code:

```
public function actionBook($id = null)
{
    $ticket = $this->findModel($id);
    $model = new TicketOrder();
    if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        // userCreate scenario
        $model->scenario = 'create';

    } else {
        return $this->renderAjax('book', [
            'ticket' => $ticket,
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

My View's code:

```
<?php
Modal::begin([
  'id' => 'create-modal',
  'header' => '<h4 class="modal-title">订票</h4>',
  'size' => 'modal-lg',
//    'footer' => '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>',
]);

Modal::end();
?>

<?php
$js = <<<JS
$(function(){
$(".modal-wraper").click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var url = "/sights/product-ticket/book?id=" + id;
    $.get(url,{},function(data){
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
    });
    $('#create-modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();
    });
    $("#create-modal").modal('show');
  });
});
JS;
$this->registerJs($js);
```

My ajaxRender view's code:

```
<?php
use kartik\form\ActiveForm;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
?>
<h3>由于资源方过多，建议一个手机号只购买一张票。</h3>
<?php
$form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'type' => ActiveForm::TYPE_HORIZONTAL,
]);
?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'fullname')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'mobile')->textInput() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'plantime')->widget(DatePicker::className(), [
    'type' => DatePicker::TYPE_COMPONENT_APPEND,
]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'comment')->textarea() ?>
<div class="button-group">
    <?= \yii\helpers\Html::a('关闭', ['#'], ['class' => "btn btn-primary", 'data-dismiss' => "modal"]) ?>
    <?= \yii\helpers\Html::button('购买', ['class' => 'btn btn-success pull-right', 'type' => 'submit']) ?>
</div>
<?php
$form->end();
?>
```

Like this:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyWF1.png)

I got error when I click the DatePicker Button.

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) (bootstrap-datepicker3.css.map, line 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been already resolved. [See it on GitHub](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker/issues/108).

Upgrade datepicker to version 1.4.2.

Comment: my kartik-v/yii2-widget-datepicker version has been 1.4.2,but it's still report error,so I request help

Comment: Have you updated to this version recently? Remove generated assets.

Comment: It's still report error when I clear up assets and generated new assets.

Comment: It's worth to report this to Kartik then.